# i can't get an update

Tags: command-line, apt, apache2

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Is another process using it (upgrade etc...)? Does it say anything else? Last time my 16.10 did that it had me run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Another process is using `dpkg` or `apt`.   Add the output of `pgrep apt` and `pgrep dpkg`.

Comment: Does it work now? By now  whatever process would have release by now.

Answer (score 0):

The following phrase in your posted question `is another process using it?` 
is probably a good hint at the actual problem.

Your described problem is most likely caused by another `apt-get` or `dpkg` instance, which can for example happen if you're upgrading packages in one terminal and at the same time execute `apt-get update` in another.

[@Feldspar15523](https://askubuntu.com/users/630512/feldspar15523) basically answered this one already.